# ¿Comó incluir de manera inteligen un archivo CSS en PHP?

Tags: php, css, poo

tengo el siguiente inconveniente para aplicar mis estilos CSS en PHP. Bueno la verdad tengo en mi archivo index.php, la estructura y funciones que necesito, por ende he estado reciclado codigó con PHP POO y importandolo con include al resto de archivos al cual le voy a aplicar lo mismo, pero hasta aquí todo perfecto. El problema surge cuado realizo la importación del código con mis estilos CSS.
El código que importo es el siguinete:

```
<?php
echo "<link rel=stylesheet href=css.css>";
class MenuPagina{
public $folder;
public $pages;

public function __construct($folder,$pages){
$this->folder=$folder;
$this->pages=$pages;
}

public function paginacion(){
$general = 0;
$t_file = glob($this->folder);
$cont=count($t_file);
for ($j=1; $j<=$this->pages; $j++) {
for($i=0; $i<=($txpages-1);$i++){
$fileExtension=explode(".", $t_file[$general]);
$fileExtension=end($fileExtension);
if($fileExtension =="jpg" or $fileExtension=="png" or $fileExtension=="gif"){
echo "<a class=\"menu menu_img\" href=$t_file[$general] target=_top>".($general+1)."</a>";
} else{
echo "<a class=\"menu menu_file\" href=$t_file[$general] target=_top>".($general+1)."</a>";
}
  }
}

public function changeFolder($folder){
$this->folder=$folder;
 }

}
$menu = new MenuPagina("*.*",4);
$menu->paginacion();
?>
```

Al momento de importarlo lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css.css">
<?php
include '../index.php';
?>
```

Pero el resultado que me da al momento de revisar el código generado en html, desde el navegador, se visualiza de la siguiente forma:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css.css">
<link rel=stylesheet href=css.css>
```

Bueno se me ocurrio esta solucón pero no funciona como se espera:

```
$includeFile = get_included_files();
if($includeFile){
echo "<link rel=stylesheet href=../css.css>";
}else{
echo "<link rel=stylesheet href=css.css>";
}
```

Este ultimo, lo que hace es dectectar si el archivo se le esta importado o no, en caso de que no se este exportando simplemente no saldra al directorio de raiz.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Consulta, porque tienes el `.css` en la rayz y no en una carpeta?
por lo general la forma correcta es ordenar el directorio, con carpetas que compriman y ordenen tu contenido dentro del portal.
en mi caso una carpeta llamada `CSS`para este archivo.

Comment: por el momento, lo tengo en raíz para no learme y borrar el css, por accidente

Comment: podrías comenzar por reordenar el directorio,
reorganizando tus documentos dentro de carpetas.
posterior a eso editas el llamado `"<link rel=stylesheet href=css/style.css>";`

Comment: listo, Francisco

Comment: Modificaste los llamados en los `.php`?
`<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

Comment: si los llamados <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>, tal cual como me indicaste

Comment: Que nombre tiene tu archivo css ? `style` era solo un ejemplo, puedes mantener el que tenias. Lo importante es mantener el orden de las rutas, me comentas como te fue..

Comment: La carpeta de css la nombre CSS y pues el nombre de los archivos los deje tal cual con la extencion .css

Answer (score 2):

Es importante que recuerdes que una clase, en el contexto de POO, es un modelo que define atributos y métodos; y sirven para crear objetos.

Con este concepto en mente, te diré que no es válido que agregues la línea:

```
echo "< link rel=stylesheet href=css.css>";
```

ya que dicha línea no es ni un atributo ni un método de la clase MenuPagina.

Continuando con el concepto de clase, tampoco es válido que agregues dentro de la clase las líneas:

```
$menu = new MenuPagina("*.*",4) ;<br>
$menu->paginacion();
```

Lo correcto es eliminar esas tres líneas de las clase, posteriormente crear un archivo de nombre menu.php, por ejemplo, y entonces, ahora sí, incluir la hoja de estilos y crear el objeto.

Por ejemplo, la página **"menu.php"**, quedará así:

```
< !-- Invocas tu hoja de estilos -->
< link rel=stylesheet href=css.css>

<?php

     //invocas a la clase
     include_once 'MenuPagina.php';

    //Creas el objeto menu
    $menu = new MenuPagina(" * . * ",4);

    //ejecutas el metodo paginacion
    $menu->paginacion();

?>
```

Doy por hecho que los archivos css.css, MenuPagina.php y menu.php estan al mismo nivel, es decir todos directamente dentro de la carpeta raíz de tu proyecto.

Comment: muchas gracias, por la sugerencia

Comment: @daromero99 esta es una solución mejor que la que tienes actualmente. En todos tus `php` que van a dibujar HTML incluyes `MenuPagina.php` y haces lo correspondiente. Obviamente en cada uno de esos PHPs tienes que ajustar las rutas relativas.

Comment: David, para resaltar sintaxis de código usa el botón **{ }** en el editor. Si lo marcas en negrita no se entiende mucho

Comment: Gracias por el tip @amenadiel, tienes toda la razón.